# Inconsistent output of word frequency count in column pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, text-mining

So I have a simple dataframe in pandas, where one of the column consist of tweet messages. Each cell or row contains a tweet message. I am trying to do a word frequency count to detect what are the top 10 words in my dataframe. Reason being to remove them from my dataset by adding them to my list of stopwords.

Tried a few code snippets on my dataset, however confused as to why it yields different results when it comes to the count of frequency. Below comparison of codes.

**Code 1**

```
top_N = 10
a = train_data['tweet'].str.cat(sep='')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
```

**Code 2**

```
word_dist = pd.Series(' '.join(train_data['tweet']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:10]
```

The top 10 most frequent words are the same in both codes but the values or count of word distribution/frequency differed slightly i.e Code 1 had a slightly lower count for the same list of words in Code 2. They are both analyzing the same dataset. The difference is around 100 words. The only difference I see is that Code 1 tokenizes the words where as Code 2 splits the words, but they are essentially the same thing so what am I missing here? I realized that Code 1 yields nltk.probability.FreqDist whereas Code 2 pandas.core.series.Series. Can someone kindly break this down to me and explain the difference please ?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `.word_tokenize()` and `.lower().split()` do not yield the exact same results. What I can gather from the docs is that .`word_tokenize()` actually uses [`TreebankWordTokenizer`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html) which is based on regex. It is way more advanced than just splitting on whitespace and will to my estimation deal better with stuff like punctuation for example.